# String is not in correct format Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, double

```
EmployeeDiscountPct.value=app.GetRegKey(Double.Parse("\Enroll\EmployeeDiscountPct\Default"))*100
```

while trying to convert in double it is giving exception like "string is not in correct format".

Comment: You seem to be wanting to parse the value _returned_ by `GetRegKey()`, rather than your string. The `GetRegKey()` method requires a string to work, and you cannot parse `"\Enroll\EmployeeDiscountPct\Default"` into a double because it doesn't consist of only numerical characters. What I think you were after is: `Double.Parse(app.GetRegKey("\Enroll\EmployeeDiscountPct\Default"))*100`.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to convert a string to double which is why you are getting that error.

You have to use numeric value instead of string to make it work as below:

```
EmployeeDiscountPct.value=app.GetRegKey(Double.Parse(12.20))*100
```

it will work.

Happy Coding.

**UPDATE:**

```
Class SurroundingClass
Private ttt As Double = 38
Private gg As Double = test(ttt)

 Public Function test(ByRef t As Double) As Double
    Return t * 10
 End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I want to pass the value by the ref and convert it to double

Comment: yes, of course, you can do it. just pass the ref variable. but make sure that variable is of integer type. (int, float, long double)

Comment: @Shashi, i have updated my answer. please check hope you got what you wanted.

Comment: If it solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: _"You have to use numeric value instead of string to make it work"_ - The sole purpose of [**`Double.Parse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx) is to parse a `String` into a `Double`, not to parse a `Double` into itself. The OP's string will of course not work since it doesn't consist of only numerical characters, but yours would if you change it to: `Double.Parse("12.20")`